# Как заставить браузер НЕ предлагать сохранять пароли?

Tags: html, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Возникла такая проблема. При попытке зарегистрироваться на сайте по нажатию кнопки "Зарегистрироваться" браузер (пока что выявлено только в Google Chrome) не перекидывает пользователя на страницу со словами *Спасибо... Вы классный чел и Вы молодцы, что зарегистрировались на этом классном сайте...*, а сразу предлагает сохранить пароль. И скрипт регистрации не срабатывает.
Отключил кнопку "Предлагать сохранять пароли" - все стало работать. Но, во-первых, не каждый будет у себя отключать в браузере ради сайта, а во-вторых, это неудобно, ведь для других сайтов эта функция может потребоваться.
Может, можно что-то в коде прописать?

**UPDATE**
Выкладываю код:

```
<form action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">Выберите тип учетной записи</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
<input type="radio" name="reg_type" id="reg_type1" value="Юзер" [[!+reg.reg_type:is=`Юзер`:then=`checked`:else=``:default=`checked`]]>
                    Юзер
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
<input type="radio" name="reg_type" id="reg_type2" value="Редактор" [[!+reg.reg_type:is=`Редактор`:then=`checked`:else=``]]>
                    Редактор
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="reg_name">
        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="name">Ваше имя:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" value="[[!+reg.fullname]]">
            [[!+reg.error.fullname:notempty=`<div class="alert alert-danger">[[!+reg.error.fullname]]</div>`]]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="reg_email">
        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="email">Электронная почта:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="[[!+reg.email]]">
            [[!+reg.error.email:notempty=`<div class="alert alert-danger">[[!+reg.error.email]]</div>`]]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="reg_mobilephone">
        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="mobilephone">Мобильный телефон:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" name="mobilephone" class="form-control" value="[[!+reg.mobilephone]]">
            [[!+reg.error.mobilephone:notempty=`<div class="alert alert-danger">[[!+reg.error.mobilephone]]</div>`]]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="reg_password">
        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="password">Пароль:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            [[!+reg.error.password:notempty=`<div class="alert alert-danger">[[!+reg.error.password]]</div>`]]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="reg_password_confirm">
        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="name">Повторите пароль:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="password" name="password_confirm" class="form-control">
            [[!+reg.error.password_confirm:notempty=`<div class="alert alert-danger">[[!+reg.error.password_confirm]]</div>`]]
            <input type="hidden" name="username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="submit" name="register-btn" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Зарегистрироваться">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <p class="pull-right">Все поля обязательны для заполнения</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality

Comment: Я так понимаю, этот параметр нужно добавить autocomplete="off"? Преобразуйте в ответ. Вдруг кому пригодится))

Comment: Вот только лучше это не добавлять - оно приносит кучу головной боли. Просто напишите свой код правильно, и все будет работать.

Comment: Ну, как бы подскажи тогда, как правильно написать.

Comment: Может, лучше показать свой код? Если код показать нельзя по какой-то причине (nda, cтыдно), то можно сделать меленький демопример, который воспроизведет проблему. Скорее всего, в процессе написания демопримера Вы сами найдете свою ошибку.

Comment: Сколько пафоса)) Вы серьезно думаете, что я сильно наошибался в форме из 2 полей? Если хотите, предоставлю код.

Comment: @Batyabest, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.